# Java Inheritance design with HttpServlet - will it cause issues

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, inheritance

I need some help I mean opinion for this inheritance design.

I have created ***Controller.class*** that extends ***HttpServlet*** and ***AjaxController.class*** that extends ***Controller.class*** and same for ***PostBackController.class***.

As you guys can see There ***SomeServlet.class*** and ***SomeServlet1.class*** that extend ***Controller.class*** and ***AjaxController.class*** respectively.

If I go on one use this design for more class that I want to create as servlets, for example, Search.class that extends Controller.classs and so on.

Will this code create any problem in the web Container as I am not directly Inheriting (extending) HttpServlet but going through a hierarchy.

Please Let me Know any problem you find with this design.
Thank you

Controller.java

```
 package utility;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import org.hibernate.Session;

public abstract class Controller extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    final protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doProcess(req, resp);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doProcess(req, resp);
    }

    public void onError(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        resp.sendError(500);
    }

    final private void doProcess(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        Session session = Utils.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
        try {
            process(req, resp, session, req.getSession(), out);
            session.getTransaction().commit();
            session.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            session.getTransaction().rollback();
            session.close();
            if (showErrorLog()) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            this.onError(req, resp);
        } finally {
            out.close();
        }
    }

    public boolean showErrorLog() {
        return false;
    }

    public abstract void process(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp, Session session, HttpSession httpSession, PrintWriter out) throws Exception;
    }
```

AjaxController.java

```
package utility;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


public abstract class AjaxController extends Controller {

    @Override
    public void onError(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
        out.print("error");
        out.close();
    }

    @Override
    final protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        this.onError(req, resp);
    }

}
```

PostBackController.java

```
package utility;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


public abstract class PostBackController extends Controller{

    @Override
    final protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
       super.onError(req, resp);
    }
}
```

SomeServlet.java

```
    package utility;

import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import org.hibernate.Session;

@WebServlet("/someurl")
public class SomeServlet extends Controller{

    @Override
    public void process(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp, Session session, HttpSession httpSession, PrintWriter out) throws Exception {
       //does some work
       //includes a jsp for view
    }

}
```

If I create more class like this will it cause any problem in web server/container
SomeServlet1.java

```
package utility;

import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import org.hibernate.Session;

@WebServlet("/someurl1")
public class SomeServlet1 extends PostBackController{

    @Override
    public void process(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp, Session session, HttpSession httpSession, PrintWriter out) throws Exception {
       //does some work
       //USED TO HANDLE AJAX REQUEST
    }

}
```

Comment: Why do you need these many servlets/hierarchy?

Comment: @SundararajGovindasamy Just for convenience sake but will this cause any problem when I add more classes that extend this hierarchy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will this code create any problem in the web Container as I am not
>   directly Inheriting (extending) HttpServlet but going through a
>   hierarchy?

If your servlet doesn't extend `HttpServlet` directly, there is no problem, provided if `HttpServlet` exists as one of the parent classes in the inheritance hierarchy.

Because you are creating too many servlet classes/instances, the real problem is that **you are violating FrontController design pattern** (which is followed by all of the popular frameworks like Spring, Struts, etc..), you can look [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/frontcontroller-135648.html) on this pattern.

The idea of FrontController design pattern is that one servlet acts as the central point for all the requests and then the request will be delegated to the respective Controller/Action classes (which are not servlets).

**Below are the major advantages of the Front Controller pattern** (taken from the above link):

> Common system services processing completes per request. For example,
>   the security service completes authentication and authorization
>   checks.
>
> A centralized point of contact for handling a request may be useful,
>   for example, to control and log a user's progress through the site.
>
> Logic that is best handled in one central location is instead
>   replicated within numerous views.
>
> Decision points exist with respect to the retrieval and manipulation
>   of data.

**UPDATE:**

> My Main worry is that will it cause any issue when 40 classes extend
>   Controller by giving the implementation of the process method like
>   SomeServlet.java. Not extending HttpServlet directly, will it cause
>   any problems?

It is a bad design and you will lose the above benefits of Front Controller.

Comment: my main aim was to reduce typing the same code again and again the Controller.java has all the boilerplate code and calls an abstract method process() in its doGet and doPost and whichever class extends Controller.java has to implement the process method only and not to deal with the boilerplate code again as it takes care of try catch and rest of the stuff. My Main worry will it cause any issue when 40 classes extend Controller by giving the implementation of the process method like SomeServlet.java. Not extending HttpServlet  directly, will it cause any problem that is my main worry

Comment: Why do you need all of them as Servlets? Why can't they be plain Java classes handled (frontened) by single Servlet class?

Comment: the Controller class is abstract and I want my servlets are bound to different url . My main worry will this cause any problems

Comment: @SukhvirThapar, I think you are trying to re-invent the wheel.